# Regular Expression in R for twitter username

Tags: r, regex, twitter, rstudio, text-mining

I am looking to handle and text between **@** and **:** with out any space for example 
@rstat:.
I would like to form a regular expression to handle this.
I have tried **^@.[A-z0-9_].:$** but its not working.

Kindly help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^@.[A-z0-9_].:$` pattern matches the start of string (`^`), then a `@`, then any char (with `.`), then letters, digits, `_`, `` ` ``, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, then any char again, a `:` and end of string (`$`). So, it can match, say, a [`` @§`‘: ``](https://regex101.com/r/Dk06Pq/2) string.

You may use *stringr* `str_extract_all` like this

```
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=@)[^\\s:]+")
```

If you must check for the `:` presence, add a lookahead check:

```
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=@)[^\\s:]+(?=:)")
                                  ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dk06Pq/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=@)` - a location in string that is immediately preceded with `@` symbol
- `[^\\s:]+` - 1 or more (due to `+`) chars other than whitespace and `:`
- `(?=:)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of `:` immediately to the right of the current location.